# Making the UI responsive and reduce the time of loading in WPF-C# App

Tags: c#, wpf

I am loading more than 1000 records from a csv file into my WPF graph chart. At this time, the UI becomes non responsive and it takes more than 5 minutes to plot the graph. After this 5 minutes the UI becomes responsive.

I tried using Threading, Background worker, Dispatcher, Task, etc. But no use at all.

Threading :

```
            Thread t = new Thread(() => RunGraph());
            t.Start();
```

Task in the **view model to read the csv file**.

```
         private void LoadData()
         {
           Window window = new Window()
           {
            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
            Content = new TextBlock { Text = "working..." },
            Width = 300,
            Height = 300                
        };
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ReadCSV();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }).ContinueWith(task => window.Close(),
            CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        window.ShowDialog();
    }
```

In the constructor of the view model:

```
      System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => ReadCSV() )); //still non responsive
```

Is there anyway to reduce this time duration and make the UI responsive ??

Comment: How are you using "Threading, Background worker, Dispatcher, Task, etc."? Please post your code. Done properly in a background worker or an async Task, you should be able to free up your UI thread.

Comment: You may want to load data in an async Loaded event handler that runs and awaits a Task.

Comment: Is it unresponsive during the time `ReadCSV()` executes or afterwards when the UI elements are rendered? If the latter, there is an issue with your view or control rather than your view model.